# Numpy: Combine several arrays based on an indices array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays of different sizes `m` and `n`, for instance:

```
x = np.asarray([100, 200])
y = np.asarray([300, 400, 500])
```

I also have an integer array of size `m+n`, for instance:

```py
indices = np.asarray([1, 1, 0, 1 , 0])
```

I'd like to combine `x` and `y` into an array `z` of size `m+n`, in this case:

```py
expected_z = np.asarray([300, 400, 100, 500, 200])
```

In details:

- The 1st value of `indices` is 1, so the 1st value of `z` should come from `y`. Therefore `300`.
- The 2nd value of `indices` is 1, so the 2nd value of `z` should also come from `y`. Therefore `400`
- The 3rd value of `indices` is 0, so the 3rd value of `z` should this time come from `x`. Therefore `100`
- ...

How could I do that efficiently in NumPy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an output array and use boolean indexing to assign `x` and `y` into the correct slots of the output:

```
z = numpy.empty(len(x)+len(y), dtype=x.dtype)
z[indices==0] = x
z[indices==1] = y
```

Answer (score 0):

`out` will be your desired output:

```
out = indices.copy()
out[np.where(indices==0)[0]] = x
out[np.where(indices==1)[0]] = y
```

or as the above answer suggested, simply do:

```
out = indices.copy()
out[indices==0] = x
out[indices==1] = y
```

Answer (score -1):

i hope this could help you:

```
x          = np.asarray([100, 200])
y          = np.asarray([300, 400, 500])
indices    = np.asarray([1, 1, 0, 1 , 0])
expected_z = np.asarray([])
x_indice   = 0
y_indice   = 0

for i in range(0,len(indices)):
    if indices[i] == 0:
        expected_z = np.insert(expected_z,i,x[x_indice])
        x_indice += 1
    else:
        expected_z = np.insert(expected_z,i,y[y_indice])
        y_indice += 1

expected_z
```

and the output is:

```
output : array([300., 400., 100., 500., 200.])
```

P.S. always make sure that `len(indices) == len(x) + len(y)` and :

- the values that are coming from y == len(y)
- the values that are coming from x == len(x)

Comment: This takes quadratic time and produces an output array with the wrong dtype.

Comment: Thanks Mehdi for the reply.
I'm afraid looping over the array would be really inefficient if the arrays are big...

Comment: @FlorianPagnoux sorry i thought you have small arrays